# Difference between takeWhile() and filter() method in Kotlin

Tags: collections, kotlin

I was doing an exercise and I found I could get the same result using `takeWhile()` and `filter()` method, so I  would like to know when I have to use one or another.

Thank you and any source you want to share with me will be welcome.

Comment: `takeWhile` will stop once it encounters an element that does *not* satisfy the condition.

Comment: takeAsLongAs is a better name, i think

Answer (score 46):

The difference between both is `filter()` method returns a list with the elements that match an specific condition. And `takeWhile()` method also returns a list with the elements that match with the specific condition but just taking in account the firsts elements on the list.

An example for that:

```
val numbers = arrayOf(3, 3, 3, 9, 1, 4, 5, 8, 96, 3, 66, 3, 3, 3)

println("*** takeWhile()")
println(numbers.takeWhile { it == 3 })
println("*** filter()")
println(numbers.filter { it -> it == 3 })
```

That will give you:

```
*** takeWhile()
[3, 3, 3]
*** filter()
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Importantly, if you made an infinite sequence, `takeWhile` could limit it to a finite sequence whereas `filter` would never finish (as it'd be looking forever for any later elements that might match)

Comment: Can `takeWhile` be used on a String?

Answer (score 7):

> filter will iterate through whole input iterator while takewhile will break once the predicate turn False,
> if you have an iterator with 1st element that false to predicate, takewhile will break at 1st iteration and return empty